# Automatic API database insertions?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have managed to fill a database of information from a popular social networking site api. This information is all of "my posts". I used json, php, and mysql to do this. Now that the database is full of all of my legacy posts I am troubled with a way of having this data be updated when a "new post" is sent through the service. I would like it so that when I "update the service" I can get that info into the database asap. What is the best way to do this automatically? Should I just manually go to a page running a php script every time I post something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a page that will update the database with your newer posts when it is loaded. Then create a cron job that loads the php file every day (or whatever interval you want).